# probability function $f(x)= \frac{c}{3^x}$, x=1,2,3... determine the constant c and find the distribution function.

Tags: probability-distributions

This question is from schaums probability and statistics:
probability function f(x)= c/3^x, {x=1,2,3...}  determine the constant c and find the distribution function.
The answer in the back of the book is c=2 but I get 2/3 since:

\sigma`$$\sigma$$` 1/3^x = 3/2 
I calculate c=2/3 not 2

The answer in the back of the book for the distribution function is 
F(x) is = 0 for x<1
        = 1 - 3^-y   y < x < y+1  {y=1,2,3...}

I integrated f(x) by dx and got  - 3^-x / ln(3)`enter preformatted text here`

Answer (score 1):

We Need $1=P(\Omega)=\sum_x\frac{c}{3^x}=c\sum_x\frac{1}{3^x}$. Now for a geometric series *starting at x=1*, the sum is $\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{1-\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{1}{2}$. Hence, $1=\frac{c}{2}\implies c=2$

As for cdf, you were integrating when you should be summing. This is a discrete distribution, so you want $F(x)=P(X\leq x)=\sum_i P(X=i)=\sum_i\frac{c}{3^i}$, where $i$ ranges from $1$ to $m$. I'm at little confused as to what you wrote, as you said $F(x)=0$ for $x<1$, which is trivial since the minimum value of $x$ is $1$. So if I misunderstood what you were saying in that second part, please let me know and I'll fix my answer

Comment: excellent, why don't you add a word on the cdf part of the question? :-)

Comment: the F(x)=0 for x<1 is a formality,  just talking about x>1. For discrete functions, is it always true that  F(x) is always equal to $\Sigma$ f(x). The answer schaums gives for F(x) is 1 - 3^y, how does that conform to $\Sigma$ c/3^i.